# Implement Multithreading in loop

Tags: c, multithreading, for-loop, pthreads

Im coding an aplication that runs the Monaco algorithm using different thread numbers, them being 2,4,6 and 8 to calculate the value of PI. The objective is too see a speed increase when using more threads. The problem is, my code is not dividing the work, but simply doing the work 2 times!

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SEED 35791246


void *monaco(int arcg, char* argv) {

  clock_t t1, t2;
  float pi;
  t1 = clock();
  t2 = clock();


  float diff = ((float)(t2 - t1) / 1000000.0F );
  printf("\n");
  printf("Thread number = %d\n", (int)(pthread_self()));
  printf("Total Time: %f segundos\n", diff);
  printf("\n");
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}


void run_test(int num_thread) {
  pthread_t pth_arr[num_thread];
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < num_thread; i++) {
    pthread_create(&pth_arr[i], NULL, monaco, NULL);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < num_thread; i++) {
    pthread_join(pth_arr[i], NULL);
  }
}


int main(count) {
  int num_thread = 9;
  int pontos=20000;
  double x,y;
  count=0; 
  double z;
  float pi;
  int j = 0;
  int i = 0;
  srand(SEED);
  count = 0;
  for (i = 1; i < num_thread; i++) {
    if (i==1) 
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (i==3) 
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (i==5) 
    {
      continue;
    }
    if (i==7) 
    {
      continue;
    }
      for (j = 0; j<pontos; j++) {
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if (z<=1) count++;
      }
      pi=(double)count/pontos * 4;
      printf ("Points used are: %d , and the Pi estimate is: %g \n", pontos,pi);
    printf ("Using %d threads.\n", i);
    run_test(i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Points used are: 20000 , and the Pi estimate is: 3.1288                                                                          
Using 2 threads.                                                                                                                          

Thread number = -1332082944                                                                                                                  
Total Time: 0.000002 segundos                                                                                                                  



Thread number = -1340475648                                                                                                                  
Total Time: 0.000002 segundos 

Thread number = -1340475648                                                                                                                  
Total Time: 0.000002 segundos                                                                                                                  


Points used are: 20000, and the Pi estimate is: 6.2932                                                                          
Using 4 threads.                                                                                                                          

Thread number = -1332082944                                                                                                                  
Total time: 0.000002 segundos                                                                                                                  


Thread number = -1348868352                                                                                                                  
Total time: 0.000001 segundos                                                                                                                  


Thread number = -1357261056                                                                                                                  
Total time: 0.000001 segundos                                                                                                                  



Thread number = -1340475648                                                                                                                  
Total time: 0.000002 segundos                                                                                                                  


Points used are: 20000 , and the Pi estimate is: 9.4232
```

How can I make it divide the work instead of doing it 2 times?

Answer (score 1):

- **Compiler Warnings**

In the early stages of learning (maybe even if you are an expert), you need to presume that the compiler is smarter than you. When I compile your code as it is, I got the following errors:

```
SO.c: In function ‘run_test’:
SO.c:32:39: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   32 |     pthread_create(&pth_arr[i], NULL, monaco, NULL);
      |                                       ^~~~~~
      |                                       |
      |                                       void * (*)(int,  char *)
In file included from SO.c:3:
/usr/include/pthread.h:236:15: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void * (*)(int,  char *)’
  236 |       void *(*__start_routine) (void *),
      |       ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
SO.c: In function ‘main’:
SO.c:41:5: warning: type of ‘count’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
   41 | int main(count) {
      |     ^~~~
```

In the first set of errors, the compiler is reporting about the incompatible pointer argument. From the pthreads man page:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

`pthread_create()` takes `void* (*func) (void*)` function pointer as an argument, but the `monaco()` function you passed is of type `void* (*monaco) (int, char*)`.

If you want to pass multiple arguments to the `start_routine()`, you need to think of some alternative approaches, for example, packing them in a structure and passing its address as an argument.

And about the second set of errors, I am surprised to see your code compile in the first place. I am not aware of the implications of such declaration, and someone else needs to answer :(

- **The logic**

Even after correcting all the syntax errors, I am not sure how your code will divide the work between threads. You are doing most of the computation in the `main()`. Maybe you are in the initial version of the code, and I don't want to spoil the fun by providing the full code :)

And for the error part, for each iteration, the value is doubling because you are not reinitializing the `count` to `0` at the start of the iteration. With this line, `count = 0;` at the beginning of the `for` loop, the output is as expected, but remember by no means your code is acceptable in the current state.

Tip: `i & 1` is an easy way to determine the odd number.